# Combo Box values do not get refreshed after delete/add/update

Tags: winforms, datatable, combobox

I am working on a windows form application using C#. A single form has tab control with three tabs. The first tab is to add records which gets updated in the db.Second tab has a combobox which is bound to a data source  (data table gets records from the db). This particular combo box just lists the values from a particular column from the table and has a view button to view details of the record user selected from the combo box.

The third tab has a similar combo box but here, i am updating/deleting the records.

Now, when i add records in the first tab, the values do not get updated in the combo box in the second tab (so that i can select the latest addition from the combo box and view the details)

In the third tab as well, when i edit/delete a particular record, that doesn't get updated in the combo boxes (both in the second tab and in the third tab).

I have followed each and every answer in SO and other forums but somehow couldn't get it to work.

I have tried setting the data source to null and clearing the combobox values and then calling the method that adds values to the combobox again, didn't work.I have three records in the dropdown, deleted the first one and it's still showing me the same three records after.

```
comboBox1.DataSource = null;
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
```

I tried setting the index to -1 as well, didn't work, it still shows the same three records.

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

I tried resetting the data table and again calling the above method, didn't work.

Below is the data source method and it gets called on Form load.

```
public void pageload()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PSDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
                try
                {
                    string cmdstr = "Select Name from PasswordSafe where Username= @Username";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login.SetValueForText1);
                    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    con.Open();
                    //DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                    adp.Fill(dt);
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    row[0] = "";
                    //row[1] = "Please select";
                    dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
                    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
                    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
                    comboBox2.DataSource = dt;
                    comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
                    con.Close();
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            
        }
```

This is the delete button that modifies the values of the combo box (just one example, i have add button and edit button as well)

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            deletepassword();
            comboBox1.DataSource = null;
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            comboBox2.DataSource = dt;
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
            //pageload();
        }
```

I tried calling the pageload() method again as well (commented line), didn't work. I tried resetting the data table as well, either it didn't work or i didn't write the correct code.

Restarting the application, solves the issue. I just need help on updating the values in the combobox instantly when i perform an operation without having to restart the application.

There's no way we can reset a form and i understand there's no autopostback in forms application.
Sure we have Selected Index Changed, don't exactly know how it works.

Also, to add to all these, the data base is actually a database file.

I hope i have been able to articulate my issue clearly. Kindly help.

Comment: Tested with TabControl, and everything works fine in my test. Could you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce this issue? Or maybe you can add breakpoint to check if the re-bind code executed.

Comment: row[0] = "" is to have the first row as blank in the combobox, not much of an issue, even if we remove it.
Also, since the combo boxes are in different tabs and the selection of the values just work as a dropdown, so it doesn't matter if the data source is same and the same selection is carried to the other tab. But sure will try to have a different data source for the other combo box.

Surprisingly, it doesn't work for me. I don't know what i might be missing. The @Username parameter is being passed on from the login page, could that might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by clearing the data table before hitting the datasource again.

```
datatable.Clear();
```

Thank you everyone for your valuable inputs.